# ファイルに最後の変数しか書き込めない

Tags: python

ファイルに最後の変数しか書き込めないです。dictionary変数に

```
{"Alphabet":{"A":{"a1_0":{0:100,1:120}},"a1_1":{0:150,1:130},"a1_2":{0:140,1:110}},{"B":{"b1_0":{0:2,1:3}},{"b1_1":{0:"4",1:"5"}}},・・・・{"Z":{"z1_0":{0:"90",1:"80"}},{"z1_1":{0:"40",1:"50"}}}}
```

という辞書が入っています。

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    x = key
    for ky,vl in value.items():
        y = ky
        for k, v in vl.items():
            z =k+ v

            s = "\n".join([x, y, z])
            f = open('data.txt', 'w')
            f.write(s)
            f.close()
```

とかいて、`x`＆`y`＆`z`変数の中身をdata.txtに書き込みたいです。
しかし、今`{"z1_1":{0:"40",1:"50"}`のdictionary変数の一番最後の要素しかファイルに書き込めませんでした。for文の中にあるのでファイルオープンで何回も書き込めると思ったのですが、なぜ書き込めないのでしょうか？

Comment: `open`の[モード](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)が`w`だからではないでしょうか？`a`に変更しては？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 一番最後の要素しかファイルに書き込めませんでした。

実際のプログラム動作は「同じファイルに何度も上書き保存」しています。その結果として、最後の要素しか残ってないように見えています。

所望の動作に修正するには、ファイルオープン[`open`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/functions.html#open)時に上書きモード(`w`)から追記モード(`a`)へ変更する必要があります。

```
# f = open('data.txt', 'w')
f = open('data.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: そもそも毎回オープン・クローズするのがおかしいのでは…

Comment: このコードだと毎回のオープン／クローズは無駄ですね。周囲処理次第では必然性が出てくることもあるでしょうけども、本題ではないので本回答では無視しました。